# Error: Thumb does not support conditional execution

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

I'm writing Assembly using Thumb for a Cortex-M7.

```
it eq                       
eoreq r1, r0, r7
pop {r0}
```

I'm using  arm-gcc to  and it throws two errors.

> Error: Thumb does not support conditional execution

> Error: instruction not allowed in IT block -- `pop {r0}'

I'm not seeing what is going wrong here, if someone could help me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: please show a complete gnu assembler command line that demonstrates the problem

Comment: was this all the code related to a minimal example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because you haven't set up unified syntax in the assembler and the old divided syntax does not support condition codes on general instructions (or so I think).  Supply the directive

```
.syntax unified
```

right at the beginning of the file to switch from *divided syntax* to *unified syntax*.  This should fix the problem you observe.

Comment: This partly solve the problem. I had some problems with the stack management which was solved by utilizing the board startup file generated by CubeMX (but that was not part of the question, just pointing for clarity)

Comment: @DiogoJDO Next time, please answer follow up questions immediately.  You got lucky that I was able to diagnose the issue without you providing the extra details, but often this is not the case.  Questions get closed very quickly if the asker is unresponsive.